# Deploy event receiver to sandboxed solution

Tags: events, sandbox-solution, hosting, debugging

I am working with SharePoint Foundation 2010 on both my development and production machines.

My production site is hosted.  I am trying to deploy a sandbox event receiver to the production site which is hosted.  I have VS 2010, but only on the dev machine.

The event receiver works on the dev machine, but not on the hosted server.  I have verified that the feature is activated.  The only difference that I made in the solution was to change the URL pointing to the Online site.  After deploying the solution to my hard drive, I uploaded it to the Online site and activated it.  I have checked spelling.  There are no error messages, it just doesn't work.

Is it possible to debug a solution when the site is hosted if they don't have Visual Studio.  How can I see what is causing the problem?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to check the SharePoint ULS logs for anything seriously bad that may have happened when the event receiver tried to deploy and/or run. They are usually located at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS`. Search for your assembly and feature name.

You could also check that the assembly actually deployed to the GAC on the server.

If neither of these help, implement some rudimentary logging within the confines of the sandbox. For example, create a custom list for logging and make the first line in your event receiver add an item to it.

(You may also find somewhat relevant [Developing, Deploying, and Monitoring Sandboxed Solutions in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335711.aspx) by Paul Stubbs.)

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Something I overlooked is that there is a site URL in the properties box when you click on the project.  I had changed the URL that was in the event receiver code, but not the site URL in the properties box.  Am I able to access the log files on a hosted site?

Comment: Only if your hosting provider allows you to. Check their FAQ/support pages or ask them directly.